# Issue in setup Sitecore Publishing Module (ver 4.3) on local system (Error: An error occurred while starting the application)

Tags: publishing-service, setup

I am trying to setup publishing module (ver 4.3) for my sitecore 10.0 application, everything has been done based on manual/script steps in document. Like configure connection string, creating IIS site, adding host entry, application pool setup etc. But seems there is some issue due to which not able browse the site.

Thus when browse url: http://sitecore.publishing/api/publishing/operations/status, it gave error: [image]

Note: My development site is on https but I am configuring my publishing service on http.
[image]
Please suggest if i am missing something/

When tried to load service from powershell, it gave error: [image]

After above issue gets resolve getting Permission issue: [image]
I have make sure that Everyone has full right on the folder to get started but then also no  luck.[image]

**Error in log :**

```
[Fatal] Unable to start Kestrel.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4092 EACCES permission denied
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.ThrowError(Int32 statusCode)
```

Comment: Could you please share what you are getting in the logs? also look like you are running a https URL

Comment: It don't enter this issue in log, in logs i only have command details. Also running it on http, not sure why it is showing Not Secure label

Comment: Now getting Access Denied error, details are given description, due to this still not able to use pub service

Comment: After some security turn on/off and restart, Hyper V turn on/off, Finally my Publishing service is started working, although i am getting that permission error in powershell, but able to browse now . Not able to select Mahendra and Sumit both answer, but upvoted them, as they helped to reach to my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it through `PowerShell` script like this.

```
.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host --urls 'http://sc910.publishing:5000' -environment Development
```

It will give you the error on the console.

Also check this article below and seems like this is a similar kind of issue.

https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2019/12/sitecore-publishing-service-410-setup.html

Might resolve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: This link talk about same issue, but in my case this dll is already unlock

Comment: Ok by running the PowerShell command did you get any logs?

Comment: i have added error details in description

Comment: @RinkuJain Your error looks the same as given in the article I have shared. Can you also try this? " I've seen this trip up quite a few people now. Another alternative to hunting the specific DLL would be to Unblock the Publishing Service zip file after download 
"

Comment: as shown in image at description, mentioned dll is already unBlock and the folder too when i had downloaded it.

Comment: please refer updated detail for error

Answer (score 1):

Your publishing service is not able to read the **"Serilog.AspNetCore.dll"** which comes with the Publishing service installation. You need to open the properties of  "Serilog.AspNetCore.dll"  and click the "Unblock" button in the popup window.
Looks like some typo or other issue in the article but it is not "unlock", it is "unblock" and you need to check this (not uncheck) -

[image]

Comment: as shown in image at description, mentioned dll is already unBlock and also the folder when i had downloaded it.

Comment: please refer updated detail for error